# Call a method inside Promise.all from Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the code block below, `var ret=that.sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(orderData);` is not getting executed. The console is printing "before calling," but it is not printing "inside `sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced`" message. Getting error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced' of null in createNewOrderHistory method.createNewOrderHistory is called from Redux Saga

const result = yield call(MyProfileRepository.createNewOrderHistory, data);

What is wrong with the code below?

```js
class MyRepository {
  constructor(callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  createNewOrderHistory(tableData) {
    var that = this;
    const AuthStr = 'Bearer ' + getToken();
    let promises = [];
    tableData.map((tableData, index) => {
      var data = {
        invoice_id: tableData.invoiceID.toString(),
      };
      promises.push(axios.post(`url`, data, {
        headers: { Authorization: AuthStr },
      }));
    });

    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
      console.log("before calling")
      var ret = that.sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(orderData);
      console.log("after calling")
      console.log(ret);
      return (results);
    }).catch(error => {
      return (error);
    });
  }

  sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(data) {
    console.log("inside sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced")
    const response = axios.post(`url`, data).then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      return (error);
    });
    return response.data;
    return null;
  }
}

export default new MyRepository();
```

Comment: Did you look at the error returned by `createNewOrderHistory`?

Comment: Your `sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced` is Async, but your assuming it's sync..  You need to make it return the promise, and then use `then`, or `async / await` on it.

Comment: @Felix .I am getting erro TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced' of null in createNewOrderHistory

Comment: How is `createNewOrderHistory` called?

Comment: It's called from Redux Saga .const result = yield call(MyProfileRepository.createNewOrderHistory, data);

Comment: That's the problem then. `this` inside `createNewOrderHistory` won't refer to `MyProfileRepository` in that case. You have to call it as `call([MyProfileRepository, MyProfileRepository.createNewOrderHistory], data)` or `call([MyProfileRepository, 'createNewOrderHistory'], data)`. See https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/#callcontext-fn-args

Comment: @Felix - Your solution works like charm.Wonderful.Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question. Can you post your solution as an answer so that I will accept it as answer

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to test your code, but I believe that @Keith had the right idea in his comment. So to test it I had to change 'url' and so on. But this code should give you a good idea on how to write it:

```
const axios = require('Axios');

class MyRepository {
    async createNewOrderHistory(tableData) {
        var that = this;
        const AuthStr = 'Bearer '; // + getToken();
        const header = { headers: { Authorization: AuthStr } };

        let promises = tableData.map((tableData, index) => {
            var data = { invoice_id: tableData.invoiceID.toString() };
            return axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data, header);
        });

        const results = await Promise.all(promises).then(async (results) => {
            console.log("before calling")
            var ret = await that.sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(results.data);
            console.log("after calling", ret);
            return (results);
        }).catch(error => {
            return (error);
        });

        console.log(results.map(a => a.data));
    }

    async sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(data) {
        console.log("inside sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced")
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', data);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            return error;
        }
    }
}

var repo = new MyRepository();
repo.createNewOrderHistory([{ invoiceID: 'test' }, { invoiceID: 'test2' }, { invoiceID: 'test3' }]);
```

If you want to run this, past it into a test.js file in an empty folder, then  run the following in the same folder:

```
npm init -y
npm i axios 
node .\test.js
```

Comment: I think the issue is with line var ret = await that.sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced(results.data);.Getting the below error TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced' of null in createNewOrderHistory

Comment: Code works fine if Axios call is made directly inside Promise. all of  createNewOrderHistory.method.

Comment: @SonaShetty: The problem addressed in this answer also exists and you would have run into it anyway after the first one (that you mentioned) was fixed.

Comment: @Felix how do i call sendSMTPEmailForOrderPlaced inside createNewOrderHistory.I am using this code inside a Rejectjs project set up.